# MS Reports Formatting numeric

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, report, numeric

I have a very simple question, but I don't seem to get it right.
I have MS Reports and I am trying to format numeric type.
I am trying to format the following 4500 to look 4.500
10000 to look 10.000
150000000 to look 150.000.000
I am trying to use FormatNumber method, but I can't get the dots, I get commas instead and it should be the dutch formatting which is with .

Anybody help?

Comment: which expression are you using to format the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this depends entirely on the locale setting on the report.

You can set the locale to German doing this:

To set the locale for a report:

1. In Design view, click outside the report design surface to select the report.
2. In the Properties pane, for the Language property, type or select the language that you want to use for the report.

[More information here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159642.aspx)